# same button for show/hide in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, show-hide

How to have the same button for show and hide in this jsfiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/ozf2vg6n/

### code bellow:

HTML

```
<button id="show">></button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<div class="defaut"><a href="#">FR</a></div>
<div class="hide"><a href="#">EN</a></div>
<div class="hide"><a href="#">DE</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.show, .hide {float: left; display: inline-block;}    
.defaut, .hide {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 40px; float: left; text-align: center; }    
.langue {  width: 60px; }    
.defaut {display: inline-block; }    
.hide {display: none; }
```

JS

```
$( "#show" ).click(function() {
  $( "div" ).first().show( "fast", function showNext() {
    $( this ).next( "div" ).show( "fast", showNext );
    $("div").show(250);
  });
});

$( "#hide" ).click(function() {
  $( ".hide" ).hide( 250 );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it with the toggle fonction:

**HTML**

```
<button id="toogle">Toggle</button>


<div class="defaut"><a href="#">FR</a></div>
<div class="hide">  <a href="#">EN</a></div>
<div class="hide">  <a href="#">DE</a></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( "#toogle" ).click(function() {
$( ".hide" ).toggle('slow');
});
```

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/dy4msc8d/

Comment: Just awesome thank you I update my jsfiddle !!     
    
 just to know can we have exactly the same thing just with css ?

Comment: I don't think you can, the hide/show/toggle functions use css to display or hide your elements but you need JS to trigger your event.

Comment: ah ok that's what i thought !!! there is a different way to have the same result only with css ?

Comment: I forgot about hover :) You can also do it that way @coolio83000 but I think you'll have more possibilities with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

with just css - only if you will show/hide on hover - not click. something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ozf2vg6n/3/ but that is not exactly same that you want

```
.wrapper {
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  width: 150px;
  // don't forget to add prefixes
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```